# Liquid flow/spill effect from bottle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, simulation

For an upcoming photoshoot, actors will be holding champagne bottles and pop them (with liquid flying everywhere). Since i'd rather not buy 50 bottles and risk getting the studio plus equipment wet/damaged, i'd rather have them hold empty bottles and have the liquid simulated in post (either using a brush or some technique).

I've looked into water brushes/water drops and none really "fit" what i'm looking for. Most of them are designed to simulate if you're dropping something into water, not having a stream of liquid coming out of an object.

Below is the effect I'm trying to achieve, any guidance/recommended brushes/techniques would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How many models will be opening the champagne? I'm not sure if 50 means 50 models each opening one or 10 models but expecting to waste a few. Also, do you plan on having any of them wet from the champagne that it'll need to match with?

Comment: I'm not planning on any of the models looking wet, rather the champagne being shot/spilled away from them. There would only be one or two models with the bottles, but in order to get that "perfect" pop shot, it would take an exaggerated (50) amount of bottles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a photographer... Photograph that... There are some tutorials on youtube on how people protect the gear and protect the studio.

#### Yes I am up to the challenge!

1. Protect your gear. All flashes inside a plastic bag. A pool of plastic sheets inside a frame. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhLGEuWfnZk
2. An "outside" studio. Prepare that on the garden shoot at night.
3. Have fun! Probably it is a great oportunity to get out of your comfort zone.

#### Ok I want some of the challenge... Sort of...

4. But do not want to spoil the clothing? Just shoot some real life cheap champagne and merge them in post-pro. One bottle will be enough for some minutes of splashing. **Try different soft drinks, inclusive some beer.** Dess an actor in the same colour of the background. Green screen technique. Probably black screen actually.

*Seeing theese photos: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=formula+1+champagne probably you can get away with mineral water for presure and some soap. Far less stickier.

#### Less splashing!

5. Probably photos at lower scale can work. Smaller spaces, no actor involved, just splashes here and there.

#### No, I do not want to get wet at all!

6. Use a 3d Rendering and modeling program with fluid simulations. Blender can work, but you will need to work hard on the materials. Work, really hard.

#### No. I want some simpler

7. Find some stock photos. Probably all splashes you can find out there are either photos or renders. A few bunch will be2D drawings or paintings, but less likley to fit a real action photo.

I think the 1-3 is more fun.

Comment: I always had in mind that if stock photos/brushes don't work out, I would have to do 3D liquid renders (which I do have experience in, but would rather not go to such lengths just for a splash). My plan at the moment is to shoot with empty bottles, and if I cannot find suitable stock/brushes, have a seperate shoot to get the water streams I need, then merge the two.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look up different paint splashes, recolor them, and lower the opacity/add a layer affect.

Comment: Hi there, Wiegley! Welcome to GD.SE! Can you maybe add a little more detail, or a screenshot or two to your answer? There are all kinds of people who come here with varying degrees of experience doing what you've described, explaining how you'd do the things you've listed would be helpful.